# Spring data with cassandra giving IllegalStateException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

I'm completly new to cassandra, so my error might be obvious.

I'm trying to create an application  with spring boot (version 2.3.0.M2) that contacts a cassandra (version 3.11.6) installed in localhost.

I've got an java.lang.IllegalStateException with the message: 
Since you provided explicit contact points, the local DC must be explicitly set (see basic.load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter in the config, or set it programmatically with SessionBuilder.withLocalDatacenter). Current contact points are: Node(endPoint=localhost:9042, hostId=16a785a4-eaf3-4a4d-a216-5244d75206aa, hashCode=7b0b99d7)=datacenter1. Current DCs in this cluster are: datacenter1

My pom is the following one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.M2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cassandra</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

In the application code, I've got a the following configuration class:

```
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    public static final String KEYSPACE = "test_keyspace";


    @Override
    public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
        return SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<CreateKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceCreations() {
        CreateKeyspaceSpecification specification = CreateKeyspaceSpecification.createKeyspace(KEYSPACE);

        return Arrays.asList(specification);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<DropKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceDrops() {
        return Arrays.asList(DropKeyspaceSpecification.dropKeyspace(KEYSPACE));
    }

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return KEYSPACE;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
        return new String[]{"com.test.cassandra.entity"};
    }
}
```

My properties file contains the following configuration:

```
spring.data.cassandara.keyspace-name=test_keyspace
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=localhost
spring.data.cassanda.port=9042
spring.data.cassandra.schema-act=create_if_not_exists
```

I also have tried with

```
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=dc1
```

When I execute the application, I got see from the logs that I'm using the following version
DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.4.0

In the cassandra-rackdc.properties I've set the name to

```
dc=dc1
```

I've done several test adding configuration parameters, even adding an application.conf to the classpath as described datastax documentation, but didn't have any success. Any clue where should I do it?

Answer (score 18):

Simply add

```
spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter=DC1
```

to your *application.properties* file, where DC1 your local datacenter name (default DC1).

Comment: Yes. As suggested by @Alexander no need for implementing AbstractSessionConfiguration. Just add the property and you are good to go.

Answer (score 9):

Since **Spring Boot 2.3.0.X** you need to explicitly provide the name of the local datacenter (because of the added Cassandra driver 4.X support which requires local datacenter to be set explicitly). You can do this by overrirding the `getLocalDataCenter` method in `AbstractSessionConfiguration`. `AbstractCassandraConfiguration` extends this class so you just need to add in your `CassandraConfig` class:

```
@Override
protected String getLocalDataCenter() {
    return "dc1";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Run `nodetool status` in the Cassandra shell. It gives you the datacenter name.

```
> root@d21e7b0dfc44:/# nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load        Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack 
UN  172.17.0.2  143.37 KiB  16      ?                 a3584baf-0665-474b-84e9-ba30528a7781  rack1
root@d21e7b0dfc44:/#
```

In my case, it is "datacenter1". This goes inside the properties file like so:

```
spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter=datacenter1
```

Answer (score 6):

[Since Spring Boot 3.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#cassandra-properties) Cassandra properties' prefix is `spring.cassandra.*`, not `spring.data.cassandra.*` (specifically since 3.0.0-M5, as can be seen from `@ConfigurationProperties.prefix` value [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.0-M4/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraProperties.html) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.0-M5/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraProperties.html)),

so you need to write

```
spring.cassandra.local-datacenter=datacenter1
```

in your `application.properties` file to set local datacenter

Comment: How to handle Cassandra authentication in Spring 3.0. I see that ```AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration```'s ```getAuthProvider()``` method has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a different config needed for Apache Cassandra to truly work with the new spring versions. It took me about 50 hours of searching before finding this out on this documentation - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra.cassandra-java-config

You'll need to create a new config file as specified there. To do this, follow thus:

1. Create a new package named `config`
2. Create a .java class file in the package named - `CassandraConfig`
3. Copy and paste the below code into it.

   `@Configuration public class CassandraConfig { public @Bean CqlSession session() { return CqlSession.builder().withKeyspace("mykeyspacename").build(); } }`

Note, change the Keyspace name to your Keyspace name defined in your property file. If you have not created a Keyspace, start Cassandra server on your system, login to the `cqlsh` on the `terminal` or `cmd` by issuing `cqlsh`, and issue this command  -

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS mykeyspacename WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 } AND DURABLE_WRITES = true ;
```

By now, when you start the spring boot app, it should run without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Its mentioned in your error logs "Current DCs in this cluster are: datacenter1"

Just add spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter=datacenter1 in application.properties

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by setting local datacenter like this :

application properties file : `cassandra.local.datacenter=datacenter1`

```
@Value("${cassandra.local.datacenter}")
private String localDatacenter;

@Bean
@Override
public CqlSessionFactoryBean cassandraSession() {
    CqlSessionFactoryBean cqlSessionFactoryBean = new CqlSessionFactoryBean();
    cqlSessionFactoryBean.setUsername(username);
    cqlSessionFactoryBean.setPassword(password);
    cqlSessionFactoryBean.setKeyspaceName(keySpace);
    cqlSessionFactoryBean.setLocalDatacenter(localDatacenter);
    cqlSessionFactoryBean.setPort(port);
    cqlSessionFactoryBean.setContactPoints(contactPoint);
    return cqlSessionFactoryBean;
}
```

Note : This is not all of the configuration code. I just wanted to show local datacenter configuration by this code snippet.

Comment: What is your Configuration class implementing or extending here? Can you please elaborate? Where is the @Override coming from?

Comment: Hi @mang4521, sorry for late answer. I've just seen your comment. Here is my implementation if you would like to review : https://github.com/aliarslan10/spring-cloud-microservice-app/blob/master/account-service/src/main/java/com/example/aliarslan/accountservice/common/config/CassandraConfiguration.java