# Not able to connect to cassandra from spring boot aplication using spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

the local DC must be explicitly set (see basic.load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter in the config, or set it programmatically with SessionBuilder.withLocalDatacenter)

Running single node cluster on localhost.

Able to query cassandra keyspace using cqlsh.

Running Cassandra Version: 3.11.8
Using Spring Boot Version: 2.3.4

cassandra.yaml configuration file untouched since downloading latest cassandra version

Cassandra Configuration

```
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      cluster-name: Test Cluster
      keyspace-name: test-keyspace
      port: 9042
      contact-points:
        - dc1
```

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:cassandra.yaml" })
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.data.cassandra")
public class CassandraConfiguration extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Value("${keyspacename}")
    protected String keyspaceName;

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return this.keyspaceName;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<CreateKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceCreations() {
        return Collections.singletonList(CreateKeyspaceSpecification
                .createKeyspace(keyspaceName).ifNotExists()
                .with(KeyspaceOption.DURABLE_WRITES, true)
                .withSimpleReplication());
    }

    /*
     * Creating keyspace if does not exists
     */
    @Override
    protected List<String> getStartupScripts() {
        return Collections.singletonList("CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS "
                + keyspaceName + " WITH replication = {"
                + " 'class': 'SimpleStrategy', "
                + " 'replication_factor': '1' "
                + "};");

    }

}
```

Getting exception when running Spring Boot application.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraConverter' defined in class path resource [lowleveldesign/facebook/api/configurations/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.CassandraConverter]: Factory method 'cassandraConverter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [lowleveldesign/facebook/api/configurations/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Since you provided explicit contact points, the local DC must be explicitly set (see basic.load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter in the config, or set it programmatically with SessionBuilder.withLocalDatacenter). Current contact points are: Node(endPoint=localhost:9042, hostId=de774b94-e7c4-4486-a75f-fda45e16e53f, hashCode=4ecec333)=datacenter1. Current DCs in this cluster are: datacenter1
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at lowleveldesign.facebook.api.FacebookLLDApplication.main(FacebookLLDApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.CassandraConverter]: Factory method 'cassandraConverter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [lowleveldesign/facebook/api/configurations/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Since you provided explicit contact points, the local DC must be explicitly set (see basic.load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter in the config, or set it programmatically with SessionBuilder.withLocalDatacenter). Current contact points are: Node(endPoint=localhost:9042, hostId=de774b94-e7c4-4486-a75f-fda45e16e53f, hashCode=4ecec333)=datacenter1. Current DCs in this cluster are: datacenter1
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [lowleveldesign/facebook/api/configurations/CassandraConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Since you provided explicit contact points, the local DC must be explicitly set (see basic.load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter in the config, or set it programmatically with SessionBuilder.withLocalDatacenter). Current contact points are: Node(endPoint=localhost:9042, hostId=de774b94-e7c4-4486-a75f-fda45e16e53f, hashCode=4ecec333)=datacenter1. Current DCs in this cluster are: datacenter1
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1175) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractSessionConfiguration.requireBeanOfType(AbstractSessionConfiguration.java:100) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractSessionConfiguration.getRequiredSession(AbstractSessionConfiguration.java:200) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractCassandraConfiguration.cassandraConverter(AbstractCassandraConfiguration.java:73) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at lowleveldesign.facebook.api.configurations.CassandraConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$331463cd.CGLIB$cassandraConverter$14(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at lowleveldesign.facebook.api.configurations.CassandraConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$331463cd$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bc26daf7.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at lowleveldesign.facebook.api.configurations.CassandraConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$331463cd.cassandraConverter(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Since you provided explicit contact points, the local DC must be explicitly set (see basic.load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter in the config, or set it programmatically with SessionBuilder.withLocalDatacenter). Current contact points are: Node(endPoint=localhost:9042, hostId=de774b94-e7c4-4486-a75f-fda45e16e53f, hashCode=4ecec333)=datacenter1. Current DCs in this cluster are: datacenter1
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.loadbalancing.helper.MandatoryLocalDcHelper.discoverLocalDc(MandatoryLocalDcHelper.java:91) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.loadbalancing.DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy.discoverLocalDc(DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy.java:118) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.loadbalancing.BasicLoadBalancingPolicy.init(BasicLoadBalancingPolicy.java:126) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.loadbalancing.DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy.init(DefaultLoadBalancingPolicy.java:109) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.metadata.LoadBalancingPolicyWrapper.init(LoadBalancingPolicyWrapper.java:121) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession$SingleThreaded.afterInitialSchemaRefresh(DefaultSession.java:444) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession$SingleThreaded.lambda$afterInitialNodeListRefresh$5(DefaultSession.java:434) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[na:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.metadata.MetadataManager$SingleThreaded.lambda$startSchemaRequest$1(MetadataManager.java:443) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:610) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:649) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultEventLoop.run(DefaultEventLoop.java:54) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.52.Final.jar:4.1.52.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Need help in connecting to cassandra from spring boot application.

Comment: Adding this to Cassandra Configuration worked
    @Override
    protected String getLocalDataCenter() {
        return "datacenter1";
    }

Comment: check my answer to fix such an issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60668792/spring-data-with-cassandra-giving-illegalstateexception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contact-points need to be pointing to an ip address. Remove cluster-name from the config.

```
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      keyspace-name: test-keyspace
      port: 9042
      contact-points: 127.0.0.1
```

Replace the 127.0.0.1 by the real address of your seed.

Answer (score 1):

```
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=yourkeyspace-name
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=127.0.0.1
spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter=datacenter1
```

add above properties to application.properties inside your application

Answer (score 1):

Before providing the DC name, I was also getting the build error. Below are properties I used for a successful build.

```
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=test_keyspace
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=localhost
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter=datacenter1
spring.data.cassandra.schema-action=NONE
```